# Need to implement django-filter with ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-filter

I am using `django-filter==2.1.0` for my search filter. Now i need to add ajax call in my search filter. My codes are given below:

**views.py**

```
def test_view(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.all()
    book_filter = BookFilter(request.GET, queryset=book_list)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'filter': book_filter})
```

**test.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="get">
       {{ filter.form.as_p }}
       <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <ul>
        {% for book in filter.qs %}
            <li>{{ book.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

**filters.py**

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    publication = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Publication.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    authors = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Author.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    categories = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Category.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['publication', 'authors', 'categories', ]
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='AuthorBook')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='BookCategory')
```

In ajax there is needed url value. django-filter works automatically. So, i can't understand how to implement ajax call with django_filter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) here you can see the way of implementation ajax call in Django.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

add `django-crispy-forms` to your requeirements.txt
usage example:

`views.py`

```
filter = YourFilterClass(request.GET, queryset=Model.objects.all())
return render(request,'template/index.html', {filter:filter})
```

`html`

```
<form method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Şehir :</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    {% render_field filter.form.customer__city class="form-control select" data-live-search="true" data-size="15" %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

after you can submit your form with ajax and it will return filtered objects